# Does relinquo take the dative?

Tags: dative

I thought that normally relinquo takes the accusative, not the dative, so I am having a hard time figuring out the following sentence:

> Ūsque ad vesperum currēbat, neque nocturnum tempus sibi ad quiētem
> relinquēbat...

"He ran until evening, and did not give himself up to rest (until night time???)..." seems to be the sense, but the grammar does not make any sense to me.

- tempus seems to be nominative, but how could it be the subject of the sentence??? Also, since sibi is reflexive, I thought that means that the person doing the running (currebat), HAS to be the subject of relinquebat.
- why would sibi be dative? I thought relinquo was supposed to take the accusative, so shouldn't it be *se*, not *sibi*?
- even if tempus is not the subject of the sentence, it does not seem to make any sense unless maybe usque is understood? So, am I supposed to read it as *neque (usque) nocturnum tempus ...* with tempus as an accusative which is the subject of the missing usque?

Comment: Note that *tempus* is 3rd declination neuter, so its accusative and nominative are the same. In this case it is the accusative.

Comment: @d_e Strictly speaking, the words "3rd declination" in your comment are superfluous :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by d_e in comments, *nocturnum tempus* is accusative here and is the direct (accusative) object of *relinquebat*, whereas *sibi* is the indirect (dative) object, so the sentence means **He ran until evening, and did not even leave himself the night-time for rest**.